# ViewFlipper inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I want to add three `ViewFlipper` inside a `ListView` but I have no idea of how I am able to add  `ViewFlippers` to my `ListView` and make them work.
as I am very new to programming, can you please explain more.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write more details. What is the ViewFlipper supposed to do inside the ListView?

Comment: sure, in my app I need these three `ViewFlipper` to show, new products,must sell items and offers, the reason that I decided to use `ListView` was because before that I used `ScrollView` in a `Linear_Layout` and put `ViewFlipper` inside it too, but when I flip the `ViewFlipper` most of the time it scroll instead of flipping, so I have thoght maybe using `ListView` can help, cause it has scroll option inside it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a `ViewFlipper` and use three kinds of `ListView` inside the `ViewFlipper`?

It might be easier to solve to problem with the `ViewFlipper` inside the `ScrollView`. You can customize settings, which `View` should receive touch events first. If the touch event is dealt with properly inside the `ViewFlipper` it won't cause unwanted scrolling inside the `ScrollView`. Let me know, if this is an option, too. There I could write a few more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, but as the way of changing views are really important in this case, so I think I have to choose an option which I`m able to set `Animation` for it, I don`t think so it is possible with `ListView`, Ii is good to know that I must use Android 2.3 to write this application